# JAXB & JPA. One to one bidirectional relationship (empty id)

Tags: java, xml, jpa, jaxb

I am using JAXB and JPA. I would like to convert data from a xml file to a database. Below are 2 examples class. When I'm unmarshalling file into java object and when i persist data i have problem with user_id in addres entity (is empty);

When i set it manualy everything is alright, but problem is while unmarshall.

Class User

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "User")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity(name = "EntUser")
public class User implements Serializable {

@XmlTransient
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column
private String name;

@Column
private String surname;

@XmlElement(name = "Address")
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "User", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Address address;


public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(Address address) {
    address.setUser(this);
    this.address = address;
}
```

Class Address

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Address")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity(name = "EntAddress")
public class Address implements Serializable {

@XmlTransient
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long id;

@XmlTransient
@XmlInverseReference(mappedBy = "address")
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
```

When i create object manually everything is ok

```
User user = new User();
user.setName("Jack");
user.setSurname("AAA");

Address address = new Address();
user.setAddress(address);

em.persist(user);
```

but during unmarshall not

```
StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
JAXBContext contex = JAXBContext.newInstance(User.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaler = contex.createUnmarshaller();

User user = (User) unmarshaler.unmarshal(reader);

em.persist(user);
```

except when i use this

```
user.getAddress().setUser(user);
```

then is ok. How can i do without this? Because my xml is more complex.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the '@XmlTransient from the User member in your Address class ?

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

JAXB offers mechanisms for pre-processing and post-processing.
After unmarshal you have to set the user in the Address class. To do this add the following callback method to the Address class:

```
public void afterUnmarshal(final Unmarshaller u, final Object parent) {
    this.setUser((User)parent);
}
```

Import the abstract class Listener

```
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller.Listener;
```

This method is invoked after all the properties (except IDREF) are unmarshalled for this object, but before this object is set to the parent object. 
For more information see:
[here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshalEventCallback)